# Process List of dictionaries from Django Rest Service Using PHP

Tags: php, python, django, rest

I'm creating a Restful web service using Django Rest Framework,

I use PHP to do the request:

```
$url = 'http://localhost:8000/cities/';
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
```

here's what I got:

```
string(88) "[{"id": 1, "code": "BJG", "name": "Beijing"}, {"id": 2, "code": "TKY", "name": "Tokyo"}]"
```

What's the most common way/best practice to process the string ?
thanks :)

Comment: what u ment by process string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be a JSON response.

Best way to process that response would be using `json_decode()` function, and you can use the `json_encode` function to do the reverse

**EDIT**

Quick summary:

`json_decode()` converts JSON String into a PHP array.
`json_encode()` converts PHP array into a usable JSON string.

Also: Here's the PHP manual; http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I got confused because it says the type is string, I thought I need to manually convert it into array, thanks for the explanation @Zander, u're helping this newbie alot :)

Comment: hehe, no problem.. JSON (in PHP), is technically a string (so you weren't wrong :D ), it's just a specially formatted string.